# Writing a pattern for a Scanner method

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

How to I write a pattern for a scanner method such as:

```
scan.findInLine(pattern);
```

That will find me the first instance of any number (that is any number 0-10000) in that line. I need this to search for that number in order to create an Array of that size.

I'm uncertain if this requires regex but if it does please can you explain it simply to me because im very new to the idea.

Examples of some patterns and an explanation of what they search for would be very useful.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Could you show example of text you are trying to parse and result you expect?

Comment: some example text would be = 0 * 1 and Im try to find the first number in that text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `(10000|\d{1,4})` will find the number you're looking for, it essentially boils down to 10000 or 0-9999

```
scan.findInLine("(10000|\\d{1,4})");
```

Comment: ok this gives me a type mismatch, cannot convert from string to double :L is this just because the return type for this method is a string?

Comment: yeah, you'll need to pass the result into Double.parseDouble http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple sample:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("ab0252c4d67");
String i = scan.findInLine("\\d+");
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(i));
```

which gives you the first number in that line. \d searches for numbers and + indicates 1 or more occurrences of numbers.